# What is this unlink script action doing and under what conditions?

Tags: centos, perl

I'm debugging someone else's script and am confused by this:

```
my $LOG = "/var/log/installfoo.log";
my $APPDIR = "/usr/share/foodir"
my $RUN_ONCE = "$APPDIR/runonce";

# check for script
if (-x $RUN_ONCE) {

    unlink("$RUN_ONCE") unless system("$RUN_ONCE >>$LOG 2>&1");

}
```

I think it's checking to see if a file exists and then deleting (and removing any symlinks) if a specific condition is met... but I don't know what `unless system("$RUN_ONCE >>$LOG 2>&1")` is doing.

- Check to see if the /usr/share/foodir/runonce exists at all.
- Execute the command if present (and write output to a log file) and then delete/unlink the file.

But I'm confused -- are there any conditions where the file would stick around? The `unless` condition of this line is confusing me.

Comment: Examine "$APPDIR/runonce".  What are the possible return values?

Comment: @user4556274 I'm told (second-hand) that the `runonce` script itself was running `yum -y remove foopackage` as part of a cleanup process. Unfortunately I don't have the script handy (presumably because it's been deleted heh).  Let's assume for the purpose of the question that it's running `yum`

Comment: Why the mark to close? I didn't see duplicate questions on the topic. Is it too specific?

Comment: I didn't close vote, but it may be because acceptable topics include shell scripting but exclude other programming.  I'd consider perl scripts within scope, but perhaps the close voters did not.

Comment: ↑ Puzzles me too. I'd put this level of `perl` in the same pot as `awk` or `sed` scripting, and therefore acceptable here. If you were delving into, say, the innards of `Net::LDAP` I'd agree with a move to StackOverflow. But not this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a shell script, it's perl. You should be able to see that by looking at the first line of the script, which may be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

The `unless` verb is equivalent to an `if not`. In `perl` it can be place either at the beginning of a statement in the "traditional" place, or at the end of the comaand to which it applies.

For example these statements are all equivalent:

```
$a = 31 unless $b == 4;
unless ($b == 4) { $a = 31 }
if ($b != 4) { $a = 31 }
```

Back to your script,

> ```
> if (-x $RUN_ONCE) {
>     unlink("$RUN_ONCE") unless system("$RUN_ONCE >>$LOG 2>&1");
> }
> ```

What this is saying is approximately equivalent to this:

```
if $RUN_ONCE is executable then
    delete it UNLESS running it returned an error exit status
```

In other words, run the program and then delete it if the run was successful.